# How to compute dotproduct with NEON and double values in ARM processor

Tags: arm, neon, beagleboard

I need to do a lot of vector calculations. Therefore I seems wise that NEON should be used. The problem is that the function depends on doubles. This gives me two options, re-writing the entire code so that it works with floats, or creating a function using doubles as input and doubles as output and doing the computations with floats.

I need to do the following computation:

```
dotproduct = A[0]*B[0] + A[1]*B[1] + A[2]*B[2]
```

the arrays are dimensioned as doubles. How can I do this computation using NEON intrinsics?

Comment: Assuming it is performance you are after and not accuracy, it is best to use single-precision every where which will let you use neon and reduce memory space/bandwidth cost.

Answer (score 4):

NEON does not support double-precision operations. You will have to either rewrite your function to operate on single-precision values, or use scalar double-precision VFP instructions instead of NEON.